# Array struct requires parameterless constructor

Tags: c++

I have written an Array struct (yes I know they already exist elsewhere, but I want to create my own). Why does my code require the item that I add has a parameterless constructor?

```
template <typename T>
struct Array {

private:
    unsigned int Capacity;
    unsigned int Count;

public:
    T *Items;

    // ***********/

    Array()
    {
        Count = 0;
        Capacity = 0;
        Items = 0;
    }

    void resize(const unsigned int capacity)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
        T *x = new T[Capacity];  //*** Error: invalid new-expression on class type SomeStruct ***//
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            x[i] = Items[i];
        delete[] Items;
        Items = x;
    }

    void addItem(const T &item)
    {
        if(Count == Capacity)
            resize();
        Items[Count] = item;
        Count++;
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] Items;
    }
};
```

If I create an array like this...

```
Array<SomeStruct> MyStructs;
```

...and call resize() like this...

```
MyStructs.resize(10);
```

...it fails on the line shown.

I thought I was calling new on the array, so why is it trying to call a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Your `resize` function is incorrect: If the `new` throws, `Capacity` will have the wrong value.

Comment: And what should be the value of the items in your array? It's trying to default-construct them. If you want it to allocate space for the items without actually _constructing_ them, you need to look into placement new.

Comment: @0x499602D2 error: no matching function for call to 'SomeStruct::SomeStruct()'
                              ^

Comment: @Useless Is there a way to do this WITHOUT placement new? What did people do before this was added?

Comment: @Beakie People use `std::vector`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah I know, I can't. Need to do this without any include files.

Comment: Do you really need this to work for types that are not default constructable? If so, I think the only way out is to use placement new.

Comment: @Beakie - `Need to do this without any include files`.  So your application uses *no* include files?  None?

Comment: @juanchopanza Ummm that's a bit sucky.

Comment: @Beakie - First, that is very hard to believe that your application uses no header files whatsoever (how would you accomplish I/O calls?).  Second, array `new` requires that the type be default constructible.  This has nothing to do with creating an Array class, those are the rules of C++.  Last, as it stands now, your class does not implement the "rule of 3" (it requires a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1) It's an API not a full application so there are no i/o or header files involved. 2) Ok, thanks 3) If you are talking about Array... there is more code... hence the "...." comment in my example.

Comment: @Beakie - API or no API has nothing to do with header file inclusion.  Not even mentioning the OS or other proprietary headers used by your compiler, here is a listing of all the C++ header files:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header  So you're saying you don't use *any* of these files?  Last, it isn't SomeStruct -- it is your `Array` class that requires proper copy semantics, which it now lacks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59472/discussion-between-beakie-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `T *x = new T[Capacity];` creates `Capacity` new objects of the type T. The default constructor of the the T is called at this place. That's why your class T needs a default ("paratemterless") constructor.

*Edit:*
The instruction `Items[Count] = item;` requires an assignment operator or a copy constructor. If both aren't avalable I guess the compiler might perform a member-wise clone.

Comment: `Items[Count] = item;` requires an assignment operator, not a copy constructor. If no assignment operator is available you get a compiler error.

Comment: How can I take an item as a parameter and add it to my array in such a way that it creates a copy of the item so it isn't linked to the instance originally passed in?